# How to URL encode http post xml data with Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, http, post, urlencode

Looking to properly url encode xml_data via http post with Ruby? I tried different variations of URI::encode(xml), and xml.URI.encode_www_form with no luck on the below ('Content-Length') code. However puts URI::encode(xml) works fine after the fact but I need to send the urlencoded xml data within the http post body for it to work properly.

```
# Server connection
uri = URI.parse(url)
req = Net::HTTP.new(uri.hostname, uri.port)

# Start test:
puts "\n\nStarting test on: #{url}\n"

# URL encoded SAML POST
SAMLResponse = %{
  <samlp:Response
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    ID="identifier_2"
    Version="2.0"
    IssueInstant="instant"
    Destination="http://localhost:80">
    <saml:Issuer>http://localhost:80:Issuer>
    <samlp:Status>
      <samlp:StatusCode
        Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </samlp:Status>

<saml:Assertion

   ID="ee4432"
   Version="6.0"
   IssueInstant="instant">
   <saml:Issuer>http://localhost:80:Issuer>

   <saml:Subject>
     <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-      vformat:unspecified">test_user</saml:NameID>
     <saml:SubjectConfirmation

   </saml:AttributeStatement>
 </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
          }

# HTTP POST | URL Encoded
res = req.post(
  uri.path, 
  SAMLResponse, 
  {
    'Content-Type'   => 'text/xml', 
    'Content-Length' => SAMLResponse.length.to_s, 
  #'Content-Length' => URI::encode(SAMLResponse), // not working
  #'Content-Length' => SAMLResponse.URI.encode_www_form, // not working
    "Connection"     => "keep-alive" 
  }
)

#puts res.body # uncomment once url encoding works
puts SAMLResponse
```

Comment: I doubt you want to ship a url encoded XML via post (that's why it is post) since you are not including it in the URL, however URL.encode does work without issues, and I assume from what I am seeing here there is nothing wrong with the posted code

Comment: Correct, the code above works in that it posts the xml, but it does not post the xml as urlencoded. I need the xml posted as url encoded for it to properly talk to this identity provider (IDP).

Comment: then you can call URL.encode on SAMLResponse right before you make the post request, and store it in a variable you would be using in place of SAMLResponse in the post request

Comment: I tried that several times and for some reason it wasnt working. Got it working now though.